# How to set Arial Unicode Ms Font for Crystal Report Chart (Pie)?

Tags: crystal-reports

Can Any one know how to Change Font of Chart in Crystal Report When I Generate Report Using C# .NET it Display Fine in my Application  but When Export as PDF Or Print this Pie Chart it does not Show my Native Language But instead it show  ‘ ?????? ’ I want to set Arial Unicode MS Font but I can’t  find any option in Chart Expert to set Arial Unicode MS Font Please Anyone  Have any Solution For  this  Problem   …..

Comment: Any feedback to the answerers? I'd like to know which answer helped you and, if not, why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Chart Expert under Text. Open Chart Expert, click on Text tab, click on Font. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio find CrystalReport menubar and go to Design after that go to defualt setting select Font tab and change your font in chart,Fields,TextObjects,...etc

CrystalReport > Design > DefualtSetting... > Font > Chart